# Text is blurred when transformed in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using `DrawingContext.DrawText` and `DrawingContext.PushTransfrom` to create rotated text on Visual Layer in WPF but as you see in the image below, the rotated text is rather blurry in some areas of the image..

Is there any option I can use to improve this? The **Arial** font is used for the text.

[image]

```
public class BeamTextDrawing : FrameworkElement
{
    private readonly VisualCollection _visuals;
    public BeamTextDrawing(double scale)
    {
        if (scale <= 0)
        {
            scale = 1;
        }
        var typeface = Settings.BeamTextTypeface;
        var cultureinfo = Settings.CultureInfo;
        var flowdirection = Settings.FlowDirection;
        var textsize = Settings.BeamTextSize / scale;
        var beamtextcolor = Settings.InPlanBeamTextColor;

        _visuals = new VisualCollection(this);

        foreach (var beam in Building.BeamsInTheElevation)
        {
            var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
            using (var dc = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
            {
                var text = Convert.ToString(beam.Section.Id);
                //text = scale.ToString();
                var ft = new FormattedText(text, cultureinfo, flowdirection,
                                            typeface, textsize, beamtextcolor)
                {
                    TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
                };

                var x1 = beam.ConnectivityLine.I.X;
                var y1 = beam.ConnectivityLine.I.Y;
                var x2 = beam.ConnectivityLine.J.X;
                var y2 = beam.ConnectivityLine.J.Y;

                var v1 = new Point(x2, y2) - new Point(x1, y1);
                var v2 = new Vector(1, 0);

                var hwidth = textsize;
                var l = Geometrics.GetOffset(x1, y1, x2, y2, hwidth + 5/scale);

                var angle = Vector.AngleBetween(v1, v2);
                var x = 0.5 * (l.X1 + l.X2);
                var y = 0.5 * (l.Y1 + l.Y2);

                var r = new RotateTransform(angle, x, SelectableModel.FlipYAxis(y));
                dc.PushTransform(r);
                dc.DrawText(ft, SelectableModel.FlipYAxis(x, y));
            }
            _visuals.Add(drawingVisual);
        }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        return _visuals[index];
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get
        {
            return _visuals.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Here is the image after using this code:

```
TextOptions.SetTextFormattingMode(this, TextFormattingMode.Display);
```

I'm still getting blurry results. Look at the middle beam text at the lower part of the image.

[image]

Comment: have you tried TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Animated" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"  ?

Comment: @HeenaPatil Yes, no improvement:(

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article - [Pixel Snapping in WPF Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Since WPF uses device independent pixels it can create irregular edge rendering due to anti-aliasing when it undergoes transformation. Pixel snapping is a means to suppress these visual artifacts by applying small offsets to the geometry of the visual to align the geometry to device pixels.

Setting the `SnapsToDevicePixels` Property to "True" for your UI elements should be able to fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks ramb00, I have applied all these methods but the result is the same. I have read that this issue was fixed in WPF 4.0 but I'm using VS2012 and the problem is still there.