# C# WPF: Blurred Text

Tags: c#, wpf, text, blur

I am new to C# WPF and working on somebody else's code.
(WPF version 3.0.6920.5011, as read from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0\Setup\Windows Presentation Foundation`)

I already gave a look to various (quite old) Stackoverflow solutions, but they don't seem related to this problem: [WPF Blurry fonts issue- Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-issue-solutions), [Text is blurred when transformed in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22953901/text-is-blurred-when-transformed-in-wpf).

[WPF: Why does text and elements blur if I use dropshadow effect on a parent item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436501/wpf-why-does-text-and-elements-blur-if-i-use-dropshadow-effect-on-a-parent-item) looks interesting, but there are no shadows applied to parents.

I observe this "blur" effect whenever an element is included in another one, and it is more and more visible as the inclusion goes deeper:

- **Device** tab's text is perfectly readable
- **Global**, **Common** and **Inputs** tabs' texts are lightly blurred
- Pane inside **Inputs** is highly blurred.

[image: blurred text]

Alas I cannot provide XAML files because of company rules, but there are no settings about ClearType, applied shadows nor to blur effects.

Is there anything else I could check? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.uselayoutrounding). It seems like anti-aliasing problem.

Comment: @Mateusz, I applied the `UseLayoutRounding="True"` to the main Grid and various elements, but there are no improvements. Is there any way to set it as default property for the whole application?

Comment: I know you said `there are no shadows applied to parents` – but looking at the image and given that the blurriness increases the lower you get in window hierarchy, please check this again. It almost looks like a transparent layer "above" the respective tab/subtab/panel.

Comment: The fact it gets worse as you go deeper makes me think you might have a style automatically applied to each parent.

Comment: Solved! It was enough to add the property `UseLayoutRounding="True"` to the top-level element.
please @Mateusz, change your comment to an answer so I can upvote it.
Thank everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your top-level `<Window>` tag:

`TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"`

This was first announced 10 years ago in [a Microsoft post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/llobo/2009/10/21/new-wpf-features-textformattingmode-for-clear-text/), it's amazing how to this day so few people use it.

Comment: Thank you. It is better than before, but it takes half a second to update the form with the non-blurred text. The initial form is blurred.

Comment: If you also want it to not blur lines and other shapes, set `SnapsToDevicePixels="true"` also.